# Symfony Ignored by DI in load configurations

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

At first my configuration file looked like this:

```
# config/services.yaml

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work. The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DBAL/*,Migrations,Form,Tests,Kernel.php,Entity/BaseEntity.php,Repository/BaseRepository.php}'

    App\EventDispatcher\Event\Api\EntityEvent:
        class: App\EventDispatcher\Event\Api\EntityEvent
        public: true
```

I transferred some configurations to another file:

```
# config/services.yaml

imports:
    - { resource: 'services/new_config_file.yaml' }   # <------ NEW

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work. The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DBAL/*,Migrations,Form,Tests,Kernel.php,Entity/BaseEntity.php,Repository/BaseRepository.php}'

    # THIS BLOCK IS MOVED
    # App\EventDispatcher\Event\Api\EntityEvent:
    #    class: App\EventDispatcher\Event\Api\EntityEvent
    #    public: true
```

In new config file:

```
# config/services/new_config_file.yaml

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work. The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    App\:
        resource: '../../src/*'
        exclude: '../../src/{DBAL/*,Migrations,Form,Tests,Kernel.php,Entity/BaseEntity.php,Repository/BaseRepository.php}'


    App\EventDispatcher\Event\Api\EntityEvent:
       class: App\EventDispatcher\Event\Api\EntityEvent
       public: true
```

As a result, I get an error like:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "The controller for URI \"/api/broker/\" is not callable. The \"App\\EventDispatcher\\Event\\Api\\EntityEvent\" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead."
}
```

I understand that only parameters can be imported? In the source code, it checks that there should be a services key

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Namely, after a deep study of the source `symfony-config` и `symfony-yaml`

Their import algorithm is as follows:
First, all files are imported (the import construct is fulfilled)
Then the final configuration file itself is parsed.

Where am I wrong?
I was mistaken in the line

```
App\:
    resource: '../../src/*'
    exclude: '../../src/{DBAL/*,Migrations,Form,Tests,Kernel.php,Entity/BaseEntity.php,Repository/BaseRepository.php}'
```

It had to be imported in the very first file (in my case, in the config / services / new_config_file.yaml file). I have this line imported in each file
Because of this, the following occurred:

The services file was imported first (config/services/new_config_file.yaml).
In my case, this is this:

```
App\EventDispatcher\Event\Api\EntityEvent:
    class: App\EventDispatcher\Event\Api\EntityEvent
    public: true
```

Then in the file config/services.yaml
This was done:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DBAL/*,Migrations,Form,Tests,Kernel.php,Entity/BaseEntity.php,Repository/BaseRepository.php}'
```

And she frayed the previous service import that I needed, because `resource: '../src/*'` It re-imports this service only with `public: true` Here we described that by default:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        ...
        public: false
```

Be careful!

Comment: By the way, the key `_defaults` should be in every imported class, this setting does not inherit the basic configuration file for the files of which it imports into itself

Comment: As you discovered, there is nothing inherently wrong with multiple service files but you want to avoid multiple files processing the same services with autowire.  Lots of fun things can happen.  This is a case where reading an re-rereading the docs comes in handy.  Your note about the _default section is there, it's just not something that might seem obvious.